# how to remove text code on single page

Tags: wordpress

I wrote a text code in page.php so it shows on every page which is what I wanted *however* I don't want it to show on one page only.

The code I'm working with is

```
<?php if( !is_single('Beef Stew') ) : ?>
    ~ your ad code goes here ~
<?php endif; ?>
```

which looks like this

```
<?php if( !is_single('Home|Artist') ) : ?>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;">NOTICE: VIDEOS MAY TAKE ABOUT A MINUTE TO LOAD</span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

once again im tryin to get rid of the text on one page only.

Answer (score 0):

`is_single`is for post types, you probably need `is_page`:

```
<?php if( !is_page('Beef Stew') ) : ?>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;">NOTICE: VIDEOS MAY TAKE ABOUT A MINUTE TO LOAD</span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Cause this code further looks good:

```
<?php if( !is_single('Beef Stew') ) : ?>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;">NOTICE: VIDEOS MAY TAKE ABOUT A MINUTE TO LOAD</span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And it's safer to use ID's, so if you change the title or whatever, the same page keeps excluded. You can find the id of the post or page in the URL, from the backend: http://winningwp.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/screenshot-showing-wordpress-page-id-in-url.png

So use:

```
<?php if( !is_page(45) ) : ?>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;">NOTICE: VIDEOS MAY TAKE ABOUT A MINUTE TO LOAD</span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: tried what you said didnt get rid of the text on that page. this is the text code <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;">NOTICE: VIDEOS MAY TAKE ABOUT A MINUTE TO LOAD</span></p>

Comment: is it possible to exclude text or is it only ads?

Comment: can i block the text code some way with this code

<?php if( !is_page(45) ) : ?>
~ code goes here ~
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: @MichealDeville, I don't know or I do understand what you're trying to say... But I edited the code for you. Just everything between the if block should be hidden on every page, except for one page! Replace 45 with the right ID of the page which should be excluded.